# Show that if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of one abelian group $G$, then $G_1=\{hk\mid h\in H\text{ and }k\in K\}$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Here's the problem:

> Show that if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of one abelian group $G$, then $G_1=\{hk\mid h\in H\text{ and } k\in K\}$ is a subgroup of $G$

I know that "abelian" means that you add the commutative property to the definition of the group, but I haven't been able to see how to use it in the problem.

So far, I've tried to suppose that $G_1$ is a subgroup of $G$ and then I tried to prove the three parts of the theorem that is in the book I'm working on: "A subset $H$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if: (i) $H$ is closed un the binary operation of $G$, (ii) the identity $e$ of $G$ is in $H$ and (iii) for every $a\in H$ is true that $a^{-1}\in H$ too.

I got stuck in (i) because I don't know how to prove the closure with the given conditions. I have $h_0k_0, h_1k_1 \in G_1 $ but how do I prove that $h_0k_0 * h_1k_1 \in G_1 $? And how can I continue to the identity?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: It's just that, as the group is abelian, $(h_0k_0)\,(h_1k_1)=(h_0h_1)\,(k_0k_1)$.

Comment: What about the identity? Can I suppose that $e \in G_1$? and how would I proceed after that?

Comment: All subgroups contain the identity, so $1\cdot 1=1\in HK$.

Comment: For a more general result that also captures yours, please read [The Product of Subgroups of an Abelian Group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57129/the-product-of-subgroups-of-an-abelian-group). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We gonna prove the point $i)$ of a subgroup chracterization.

$i)$ Let $x,y\in G_1$ then $x=h_1k_1$ and $y=h_2k_2$ where $h_1h_2\in H$ and $k_1,k_2\in K$ then
$$xy=(h_1k_1)(h_2k_2)=(h_1h_2)(k_1k_2)$$ since $G$ is connmutative and $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$ then as a subset their
inherit the property of be  connmutative.

hence $G_1$ is closed under the sum.

Now for the identity, let us denote by $1_G$ be the identity of $G$, since $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$ their have the identity of $G$ it is $1_G\in H$ and $1_G\in K$ now what product of $h_1k_1$ you should consider to get $1_G$?

Easy since we can use $1_G1_G=1_G\in G_1$ .

for the least propery $iii)$ (the existence of inverses) you can read the Shaun Post.

Comment: Brien, soy de Colombia, podemos hablar en español si quieres. Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero aún estoy perdido para (ii) (iii)

Comment: Muy bien perfecto, Eso prueba $i)$ y $ii)$ la parte $iii)$ de que todo elemento de $G$ tiene inverso la puedes leer de manera muy clara en la respuesta de Shaun.

Comment: ¿Por qué la respuesta de Shaun es correcta? No estoy seguro. O quizá es porque no veo que se asegure que la multiplicación por el inverso, dé la identidad. No entiendo bien la última línea

Comment: My answer is correct, @Scoofjeer, because it makes use of the one-step subgroup test; see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Subgroup_Test) for proof. I made use of the lemma that $(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}$ for all $x,y$ in any group. If you have any further questions, please let me know by commenting on my answer.

Comment: More to the point, @Scoofjeer, if you let $f=e$ in my answer, you get $fg^{-1}=eg^{-1}=g^{-1}\in HK$.

Answer (score 3):

Already there is a good answer above, so I try to provide a general, famous theorem in abstract algebra. The theorem statement is,

**If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$ (not necessarily abelian) such that $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then the set $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$.**

Proof: Pick two elements $h_{1}k_{1}$ and $h_{2}k_{2}$ of $HK$. Then,
$$h_{1}k_{1}(h_{2}k_{2})^{-1}=h_{1}k_{1}k_{2}^{-1}h_{2}^{-1}=(h_{1}h_{2}^{-1})\cdot(h_{2}k_{1}h_{2}^{-1})\cdot(h_{2}k_{2}^{-1}h_{2}^{-1}) \in HK$$
since $h_{1}h_{2}^{-1} \in H$ and $(h_{2}k_{1}h_{2}^{-1})\cdot(h_{2}k_{2}^{-1}h_{2}^{-1}) \in K$ by the definition of the normal subgroup.

If you accept this theorem, then your question is obviously solved since any subgroup of an abelian group is normal.

I hope my answer is helpful for you to get a wider viewpoint.

Comment: Hi! May I ask why $(h_2 k_1 h_2^{-1}) \cdot (h_2 k_2^{-1} h_2^{-1}) \in K$ ?

Comment: Hello. Since each element of $h_{2}k_{1}h_{2}^{-1}$ and $h_{2}k_{2}^{-1}h_{2}^{-1}$ is an element of $K$, the product of them are obviously contained in $K$. In addition, the reason why $h_{2}k_{1}h_{2}^{-1} \in K$ is the normal subgroup property of $K$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test#:%7E:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20the%20one,is%20also%20in%20the%20subset.). The standard notation for $G_1$ is $HK$.

Since $e\in H$ and $e\in K$, we have $e=ee\in HK$. Thus $HK\neq\varnothing$.

Let $g=hk\in HK$ for $h\in H$ and $k\in K$. Then, since $H\le G$, $K\le G$, and $G$ is closed under multiplication, we have $g\in G$. Hence $HK\subseteq G$.

Let $f=ab, g=hk\in HK$ for $a,h\in H$, $b,k\in K$. Then

$$\begin{align}
fg^{-1}&=(ab)(hk)^{-1}\\
&=abk^{-1}h^{-1}\\
&=(ah^{-1})(bk^{-1}),
\end{align}$$

but $ah^{-1}\in H$ as $H\le G$ and $bk^{-1}\in K$ as $K\le G$. Hence $fg^{-1}\in HK$.

Hence $HK\le G$.

Answer (score 0):

Closure under addition:

$$(h_1k_1)(h_2k_2)=h_1(k_1h_2)k_2 = h_1(h_2k_1)k_2=(h_1h_2)(k_1k_2)\in HK $$
Closure under inverse:
$$ (hk)^{-1} = k^{-1}h^{-1}=h^{-1}k^{-1}\in HK$$
Thus HK is a subgroup.